# creating a regular expression in python with variables and a comma

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match and find names exactly from one list with another list using python.

```py
# First List
file = 'Last_First.csv'
filename = file.split('_')
last = filename[0]
first = filename[1]
```

search a large list of names where names are saved as `Last, First`

```
pattern = re.compile(re.escape(last+','+first))
# Second List
['63', 'Last, First', '65164345']
```

when i search the list line by line, i get an empty list

```
matches = pattern.findall(line)
```

printing the `pattern`, i get

```
re.compile(r'Last\,First', re.UNICODE)
```

how can i get rid of `\` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `\` is an escape character that has to be there. You are getting an empty list because `'Last, First'` has a space after the comma, your regular expression is not matching that space.